# Rotate around a horizontal line

Tags: integration

We have the functions $f(x) = 10 - x^2$ and $g(x) = 2^{x+2}$. V is the region bound by the two curves. Find the volume of the body M which forms when V is rotated around the line $y=10$.

I have been told to first perform a translation, to make it $f(x) = -x^2$ and $g(x) = 2^{2x+2} - 10$, but after that I'm lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the picture below to find out the suggestion.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the effort!! +1 and accepted